# How should I call the complement of a credible region?

Tags: bayesian, terminology, credible-interval

Incredible interval/region?

More explicitly, if I have a unimodal distribution with a 95% credible interval in [A,B], what would I call the complementary region ]A,B[? It is 100% credible region minus the 95% credible region. I would like to know the most concise, most obvious name, that needs no further explanation when said to a statistician.

Comment: I am not saying this is "the" correct term, but how about "non-credible region(s)"?  For instance, see p. 2 of http://midag.cs.unc.edu/pubs/papers/SPIE07-Levy.pdf .

Comment: I like "incredible region" :-).

Comment: Non-credible sounds good. So "xx% non-credible regions" would be a clear-enough name?